# AngularJs 1.x: Remove dynamically created scope and de-register controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I created a scope and controller dynamically from my code (*usually from a provider*) as given below

```
var controllerFn = function ($scope) {
  /* scope functions and variables */
  $scope.$on('custom_ng_event', function (evt) {
    console.log('Custom evt listened in dynamic scope');
  });
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    console.log('Dynamically created scope destroyed');
  });
}
var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
var ctrlInstance = $controller(controllerFn, {$scope: $scope});
```

I want to remove the scope and de-register the controller at a certain point. I thought that $scope.$destroy() would do the task, but I think I'm missing something as it is not giving the expected result. Like, any broadcast to the $rootScope is still being reflected in the dynamically created scope listener.

Please help me to understand what I have done wrong.

Additional Info:
I preference is to have my dynamically created scope to be a child scope of root scope (*directly*) because it is meant to be used for the whole application (*similar to that of a modal*).

Thanks in advance
Balu

Comment: One thing that caught my eye is that the `$on` is not deregistered in the destroy. You need to save the registered event and in the `$destroy` event, clean it.

Comment: Oh, I missed this. I retried the example with what you have said. Now it looks something like
  var lis = $scope.$on('custom_ng_event', function (evt) {
    console.log('Custom evt listened in dynamic scope');
  });
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    console.log('Dynamically created scope destroyed');
    lis();
  });

The application threw an error. Then I noticed that I was loading a custom implementation of AngularJs which was used for checking certain behavior of our app.

I loaded the latest AngularJS from CDN and there was no error. It worked fine. :)

Thanks a lot